# Observable forking with rxJava

Tags: rx-java

I want to process data records using reactive programming.

I need to filter the records first according to some rules.

- Bad records are only consumed by a Subscriber
- Good records go down in the pipeline to be processed by more processor

```
                                            | -> RejectedRecordsSubscriber
                                            |
RecordPublisher ---> RecordMatcherProcessor ---> RecordProcessor ---> ...
```

I don't feel comfortable with splitting with 2 filters() operators because the filter process is quite expensive.

I would rather filter once and publish the record to the correct subscriber.

How is it possible with rxJava? Is using groupBy operator the only way?

Note: in my POC written with the Java Flow API, the object type of subscribers is known, so I can to publish to one or the other subscriber.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are ways, however, chaining processors in RxJava is not a good approach as that tends not to link up cancellations properly. You could just create 2 identity processors, one for each filter outcome and have the filter post to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it by using [Subject](https://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).

Example code:

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Long> recordPublisher = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        PublishSubject<Long> goodRecordSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        PublishSubject<Long> badRecordSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        //Record Match Process
        recordPublisher.subscribe(i -> {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                goodRecordSubject.onNext(i);
            } else {
                badRecordSubject.onNext(i);
            }
        });

        //Now deal with the good record;
        goodRecordSubject.subscribe(
                i -> System.out.println("get good record: " + i)
        );

        //Deal with the bad record;
        badRecordSubject.subscribe(
                i -> System.out.println("get bad record: " + i)
        );

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```